# Mx player network stream

Tags: android, networkstream

I have some http://  type url links for live TV streams, that I would like to use in my "Live TV app" project. These links open up and play in MX Player with no problem when I enter them manually in network stream window. But, in my app; when I click on the same link, it wants to open up in  a browser instead (system thinks that is a regular web site link-I guess). **I want this link to open in MX Player when it's clicked on it.** 
Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code and replace your link to open a http streaming link in MX player:

```js
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setPackage("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad");
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"), "video/h264"); 
startActivity(i);
```